# How do I sort array of names first by last names and then by first name and middle name in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a set of names which I want to sort first by `last name` and then by `first name` and finally by `middle name`. The `middle name` could be more than `1`. For example, if I have an array with the names:

```
["James Morrison", "Billy Z Joel", "Billy Joel", "Billy A Joel"]
```

How do I sort it to be:

```
["Billy Joel", "Billy A Joel", "Billy Z Joel", "James Morrison"]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything from your side to find the solution?

Comment: In Javascript, there's an array method called `sort()` for sorting array items in the right order. Check it out on this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use [String.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with a regular expression to split the `surname` from the `other names` inside [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). Then you can use [String.localeCompare()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) to first compare the `surnames` and if they are equals then compare the `other names`. Note that on this approach you will need at leats one `first name` and one `surname` for each element on the array, or it will not work. Also, the method [Array.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) was only used with the purpose to not mutate (change) the original array, but you can discard it if you don't mind that.

```js
const names = ["James Morrison","Billy Z Joel","Billy Joel","Billy A Joel", "James Junior Joseph Morrison"];

let res = names.slice().sort((a, b) =>
{
    let [aNames, aSurname] = a.match((/(.*)\s(\w+)$/)).slice(1);
    let [bNames, bSurname] = b.match((/(.*)\s(\w+)$/)).slice(1);

    if (aSurname.localeCompare(bSurname))
        return aSurname.localeCompare(bSurname);
    else
        return aNames.localeCompare(bNames);
});

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```